# props.clickHandler is not a function (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hi I've searched around and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have an array of JSX elements:

```
  inputList: [<span contentEditable="false" className="word" onClick={(e) => { props.clickHandler(e) }}>hey</span>, <span contentEditable="false" className="word">there</span>]
```

Each of these elements have an event Handler attached to them. which is the "onClick" one.

```
  onClick={(e) => { props.clickHandler(e)}}
```

Each of these elements are rendered in this component:
(the list of JSX elements are passed in with "props.text")

```
export default function Draft(props) {
  return (
    <div className="draft-container">
      <form className="draft-form">
        <div onDoubleClick={() => { props.onClick() }} onChange={(e) => { 
             props.textChange(e) }} className="draft-input" 
             contentEditable="true" >
             {props.text}
        </div>
        <button className="clear-btn" value="Clear">Clear</button>
        <button className="finalize-btn" value="Finalize">Finalize</button>
      </form>
    </div >

  )
}
```

When I view the app in browser and try to click on the span element, I get an error: "props.clickHandler is not a function"

Also here is the code for props:

```
 clickHandler={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

and for the event handler:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    alert('IT WORKS!')

  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

edit:

sorry I forgot to add I have prop called "text" where InputList is used:

```
text={this.state.inputList}
```

the whole component with props:

```
 <Draft onClick={() => { this.strikeThrough() }} textChange={(e) => { this.textChange(e) }} text={this.state.inputList}
      clickHandler={this.handClick.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Can you show where `inputList` is actually used?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add I have prop called "text":

I updated the post, thanks!

Comment: You realise that, you have assigned `onClick` to only one of your `<span>` elements?

Comment: Yes, I added only one click handler for testing purposes.

Comment: Where is `clickHandler={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` in the code?

Comment: this is passed in as a prop in the Draft  component (last block of code in post) which is nested in my root component.

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your code :

```
clickHandler={this.handClick.bind(this)}
```

should be

```
clickHandler={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```